# Put entries of numpy matrix of differing column length into a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'm working in Python. I have a numpy array of length L, called "arr", `arr = np.empty(L, dtype = object)` where every entry of arr contains another numpy array, but **each with a different length** (that's why I used dtype = object). Now I want to most efficently take every entry contained in arr and put it into one big 1D numpy array. So in other words I want to have a numpy array with `array([arr[0,0], arr[0,1], arr[0,2], ... , arr[1,0], arr[0,1], ...])` in this specific order where the. Any help on how to write this in Pyhton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to flatten a nested list.  That is, your array of arrays is effectively a list of lists.  There's a standard Python idiom for that, `itertools.chain`:

Make a sample array of arrays:

```
In [828]: arr = np.array([np.arange(i) for i in range(1, 5)])
In [829]: arr
Out[829]: array([array([0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Import and use chain.  `*arr` expands `arr` as though it were a list:

```
In [830]: from itertools import chain
In [831]: list(chain(*arr))
Out[831]: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3]
In [832]: np.array(_)
Out[832]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

But the list of arrays description also suggests we can use `np.concatenate` (or `np.hstack`):

```
In [837]: np.concatenate(arr)
Out[837]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

That is `concatenate` takes a 'list', e.g. and joins them end end (on the only axis).

```
In [841]: list(arr)
Out[841]: [array([0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [flatten()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) method? I think it might work here.

```
>>> arr = np.identity(5)
>>> arr.shape
(5, 5)
>>> arr = arr.flatten()
>>> arr.shape
(25,)
```